# Apply Catalog Price Rule to lower price instead of regular price

Tags: ee-1.13, catalog-price-rules

I'm trying to see if it's possible to apply Catalog Price Rules to the lower selling price between `price` or `special_price`. Right now, such rules apply to the regular `price`. I'm looking at the `Mage_CatalogRule` module at places like `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Action_Index_Refresh::_calculatePrice`, and doing this doesn't seem like a simple task.

From what I can gather, `Mage_CatalogRule` creates a temporary table from which the rule prices are calculated. This is a MySQL `TEMPORARY` table. However, I'm having a hard time finding where it's actually filling in this temporary table. in `_fillIndexData()`, it's making references to the temporary index tables already (or is it just preparing the select statement?), even though the table is not yet populated (correct me if I'm wrong).

I'm just generally confused because I'm not familiar with "preparing" SQL statements using objects and running a long query all at once.

Any ideas or leads?